correlation table with modelsummary
I am trying to generate a correlation table using the datasummary_correlation() function from the modelsummary package. I am using a custom function corstars to display significance levels with asterisks.
Here is my custom corstars function:
# Correlations Function
corstars <- function(x, method=c("pearson", "spearman"), removeTriangle=c("upper", "lower"),
                     result=c("none", "html", "latex")){
  require(Hmisc)
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  correlation_matrix <- rcorr(x, type=method[1])
  R <- correlation_matrix$r # Matrix of correlation coefficients
  p <- correlation_matrix$P # Matrix of p-values
  
  # Define notions for significance levels; spacing is important.
  mystars <- ifelse(p < .01, "*** ", ifelse(p < .05, "**  ", ifelse(p < .10, "*   ", "    ")))
  
  # Truncate the correlation matrix to two decimal places
  R <- format(round(cbind(rep(-1.11, ncol(x)), R), 2))[,-1]
  
  # Build a new matrix that includes the correlations with their appropriate stars
  Rnew <- matrix(paste(R, mystars, sep=""), ncol=ncol(x))
  diag(Rnew) <- paste(diag(R), " ", sep="")
  rownames(Rnew) <- colnames(x)
  colnames(Rnew) <- paste(colnames(x), "", sep="")
  
  # Remove upper triangle of correlation matrix
  if(removeTriangle[1] == "upper"){
    Rnew <- as.matrix(Rnew)
    Rnew[upper.tri(Rnew, diag = TRUE)] <- ""
    Rnew <- as.data.frame(Rnew)
  }
  # Remove lower triangle of correlation matrix
  else if(removeTriangle[1] == "lower"){
    Rnew <- as.matrix(Rnew)
    Rnew[lower.tri(Rnew, diag = TRUE)] <- ""
    Rnew <- as.data.frame(Rnew)
  }
  
  # Remove last column and return the correlation matrix
  Rnew <- cbind(Rnew[1:length(Rnew)-1])
  if (result[1] == "none") return(Rnew)
  else{
    if(result[1] == "html") print(xtable(Rnew), type="html")
    else print(xtable(Rnew), type="latex")
  }
} 

When I run the following code:
modelsummary::datasummary_correlation(mtcars, method = corstars)

I get the following error:
Error in modelsummary::datasummary_correlation(mtcars, method = corstars) : 
  The function supplied to the 'method' argument did not return a square matrix or data.frame with row.names and colnames.

I want to generate a correlation table with asterisks for significance levels using datasummary_correlation(). For example, running corstars(mtcars) should produce the desired table.
How can I modify my function or approach to make datasummary_correlation() work correctly with the corstars function?

Please read the error message attentively:

Error in modelsummary::datasummary_correlation(mtcars, method = corstars) :
The function supplied to the ‘method’ argument did not return a square matrix
or data.frame with row.names and colnames.

Your function does not return a square matrix. It has more rows than columns. I suspect that if you fix that, your problem will disappear.
dat <- subset(iris, select = -Species)
cormat <- corstars(subset(iris, select = -Species))

dim(cormat)
> [1] 4 3

